# How to configure oAuth2 with password flow with Swagger ui in spring boot rest application

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I have spring boot rest api (resources) which uses another spring boot authorisation server, I have added Swagger config to the resource application to get a nice and quick documentation/test platform for the rest API. my Swagger config looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {    

    @Autowired
    private TypeResolver typeResolver;

    @Value("${app.client.id}")
    private String clientId;
    @Value("${app.client.secret}")
    private String clientSecret;
    @Value("${info.build.name}")
    private String infoBuildName;

    public static final String securitySchemaOAuth2 = "oauth2";
    public static final String authorizationScopeGlobal = "global";
    public static final String authorizationScopeGlobalDesc = "accessEverything";

    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 

        List<ResponseMessage> list = new java.util.ArrayList<ResponseMessage>();
        list.add(new ResponseMessageBuilder()
                .code(500)
                .message("500 message")
                .responseModel(new ModelRef("JSONResult«string»"))
                .build());
        list.add(new ResponseMessageBuilder()
                .code(401)
                .message("Unauthorized")
                .responseModel(new ModelRef("JSONResult«string»"))
                .build());


        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())     
          .build()
          .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(securitySchema()))
          .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()))
          .pathMapping("/")
          .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class,String.class)
          .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)
          .alternateTypeRules(
              newRule(typeResolver.resolve(DeferredResult.class,
                      typeResolver.resolve(ResponseEntity.class, WildcardType.class)),
                  typeResolver.resolve(WildcardType.class)))
          .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
          .apiInfo(apiInfo())
          .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET,list)
          .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.POST,list);
    }


    private OAuth securitySchema() {

        List<AuthorizationScope> authorizationScopeList = newArrayList();
        authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("global", "access all"));

        List<GrantType> grantTypes = newArrayList();
        final TokenRequestEndpoint tokenRequestEndpoint = new TokenRequestEndpoint("http://server:port/oauth/token", clientId, clientSecret);
        final TokenEndpoint tokenEndpoint = new TokenEndpoint("http://server:port/oauth/token", "access_token");
        AuthorizationCodeGrant authorizationCodeGrant = new AuthorizationCodeGrant(tokenRequestEndpoint, tokenEndpoint);

        grantTypes.add(authorizationCodeGrant);

        OAuth oAuth = new OAuth("oauth", authorizationScopeList, grantTypes);

        return oAuth;
    }


    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth())
                .forPaths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/**")).build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {

        final AuthorizationScope authorizationScope =
                new AuthorizationScope(authorizationScopeGlobal, authorizationScopeGlobalDesc);
        final AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
        return Collections
                .singletonList(new SecurityReference(securitySchemaOAuth2, authorizationScopes));
    }



    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title(“My rest API")
                .description(" description here … ”)
                .termsOfServiceUrl("https://www.example.com/")
                .contact(new Contact(“XXXX XXXX”,
                                     "http://www.example.com", “xxxx@example.com”))
                .license("license here”)
                .licenseUrl("https://www.example.com")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .build();
    }

}
```

The way I get the access token from the Authorisation server is by using http POST to this link with basic authorisation in the header for clientid/clientpass:

```
http://server:port/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>
```

the response is something like:

```
{
    "access_token": "e3b98877-f225-45e2-add4-3c53eeb6e7a8",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "58f34753-7695-4a71-c08a-d40241ec3dfb",
    "expires_in": 4499,
    "scope": "read trust write"
}
```

in Swagger UI I can see an Authorisation button, which opens a dialog to make the authorisation request, but it is not working and directing me to a link as following,

```
http://server:port/oauth/token?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fserver%3A8080%2Fwebjars%2Fspringfox-swagger-ui%2Fo2c.html&realm=undefined&client_id=undefined&scope=global%2CvendorExtensions&state=oauth
```

what I am missing here?

[image: Swagger UI has an Authorisation button]

Comment: I have the same issue with .netcore app and Identity Server. I can get the token with the `http://<identityServerUrl>:<port>/connect/token` using postman or curl, but the swagger ui directs me to a link instead...

Comment: see my workaround posted as a potential answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

After 8 months, finally the password flow is supported in Swagger UI, here is the final code and settings which works for me:

1) Swagger Config:

```
package com.example.api;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import springfox.documentation.schema.ModelRef;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.AuthorizationScope;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.service.GrantType;
import springfox.documentation.service.OAuth;
import springfox.documentation.service.ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant;
import springfox.documentation.service.ResponseMessage;
import springfox.documentation.service.SecurityReference;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ResponseMessageBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.SecurityContext;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiKeyVehicle;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SecurityConfiguration;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.*;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Value("${app.client.id}")
    private String clientId;
    @Value("${app.client.secret}")
    private String clientSecret;
    @Value("${info.build.name}")
    private String infoBuildName;

    @Value("${host.full.dns.auth.link}")
    private String authLink;

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {

        List<ResponseMessage> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(500).message("500 message")
                .responseModel(new ModelRef("Result")).build());
        list.add(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(401).message("Unauthorized")
                .responseModel(new ModelRef("Result")).build());
        list.add(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(406).message("Not Acceptable")
                .responseModel(new ModelRef("Result")).build());

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build().securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(securitySchema()))
                .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext())).pathMapping("/")
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false).apiInfo(apiInfo()).globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET, list)
                .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.POST, list);



    }

    private OAuth securitySchema() {

        List<AuthorizationScope> authorizationScopeList = newArrayList();
        authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("read", "read all"));
        authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("trust", "trust all"));
        authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("write", "access all"));

        List<GrantType> grantTypes = newArrayList();
        GrantType creGrant = new ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant(authLink+"/oauth/token");

        grantTypes.add(creGrant);

        return new OAuth("oauth2schema", authorizationScopeList, grantTypes);

    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).forPaths(PathSelectors.ant("/user/**"))
                .build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {

        final AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[3];
        authorizationScopes[0] = new AuthorizationScope("read", "read all");
        authorizationScopes[1] = new AuthorizationScope("trust", "trust all");
        authorizationScopes[2] = new AuthorizationScope("write", "write all");

        return Collections.singletonList(new SecurityReference("oauth2schema", authorizationScopes));
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityConfiguration securityInfo() {
        return new SecurityConfiguration(clientId, clientSecret, "", "", "", ApiKeyVehicle.HEADER, "", " ");
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("My API title").description("")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("https://www.example.com/api")
                .contact(new Contact("Hasson", "http://www.example.com", "hasson@example.com"))
                .license("Open Source").licenseUrl("https://www.example.com").version("1.0.0").build();
    }

}
```

2) in POM use this Swagger UI version 2.7.0:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

3) in the application.properties add the following properties:

```
host.full.dns.auth.link=http://oauthserver.example.com:8081
app.client.id=test-client
app.client.secret=clientSecret
auth.server.schem=http
```

4) in the Authorisation server add a CORS filter:

```
package com.example.api.oauth2.oauth2server;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Allows cross origin for testing swagger docs using swagger-ui from local file
 * system
 */
@Component
public class CrossOriginFilter implements Filter {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CrossOriginFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

        // Called by the web container to indicate to a filter that it is being
        // placed into service.
        // We do not want to do anything here.
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        log.info("Applying CORS filter");
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "0");
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

        // Called by the web container to indicate to a filter that it is being
        // taken out of service.
        // We do not want to do anything here.
    }
}
```

If you run with these settings you will get the authorize button in the link http://apiServer.example.com:8080/swagger-ui.html#/   (if you run on 8080) as follows:

[image]

Then when you click on the authorize button you will get the following dialogue, add the data for your username/password and the client id and the client secret, the type has to be request body, I am not sure why but this is what works with me, although I thought it should be basic auth as this is how the client secret is sent, anyway this is how Swagger-ui works with password flow and all your API endpoints are working again.  Happy swaggering!!! :)

[image]

Comment: A bit of formatting issue, I guess , `newArrayList();` would be `new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Thanks @Hasson , Authorize button got enabled, but APIS's are not working for me. Seems not sending the token with the request. Can you please help again

Comment: could share class that extends `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` ? do you have `.antMatchers("/swagger*", "/v2/**").permitAll()` in there ?

Comment: I have them in the class which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` sorry cannot share that as it contains some security features in the application.

Comment: Is it possible to configure that the swager-ui to request new access token with refresh token ?

Comment: not to the best of my knowledge, it will be great if this functionality is available, please comment here if you find a way.

Comment: If you want to use basic auth (recommended) instead creds into the request body, you have to allow CORS for `/oauth/token` and always give an `HTTP 200` to `OPTIONS /oauth/token`. Sending client id & client secret into the request body is not recommended by OAuth 2.0.

Comment: @Hasson, Thanks for the answer, But i got the same issue like "@Ranjith". I'm able to authenticate but the token not bind with requested APIs.

Comment: curl -X GET "http://localhost:9001/api/v1/privilege?limit=10&order_by=privilege&order_type=asc&page_no=1" -H "accept: */*"

Comment: @Ranjith do you get any answer of your mentioned point in comment? I face the same issue.

Comment: This was a bug and solved in the latest versions (2.9.2 and bove) of springfox

Comment: do anybody have repository on git? i actually want to clone an go through it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure as what was the issue for you but **Authorize** button is working for me for swagger version 2.7.0, though I have to get JWT token manually.

First I make a hit for auth token then I insert token like below,

[image]

Key here is that my tokens are JWT and I was not able to insert token value after **Bearer ** and changing **api_key** name to **Authorization** and that I achieved with below Java configuration ,

```
@Bean
    public SecurityConfiguration securityInfo() {
        return new SecurityConfiguration(null, null, null, null, "", ApiKeyVehicle.HEADER,"Authorization",": Bearer");
    }
```

There seems a bug in swagger about **scope separator** which by default is **:** . In my config, I tried to modify it to `: Bearer`but that is not happening so I have to enter that on UI .

Answer (score 0):

The best way so far to work with oAuth2 Authorisation is by using Swagger Editor, I have installed Swagger Editor quickly in Docker (from [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/swaggerapi/swagger-editor/)), then used the import parameter to download the API JSON descriptor (your API should include CORS filter), then I can get Swagger Documentation and an interface where I can add a token which I get using curl, postman, or Firefox rest client.

The link which I am using now looks like this

`http://docker.example.com/#/?import=http://mywebserviceapi.example.com:8082/v2/api-docs&no-proxy`

the interface in Swagger Editor to enter the token looks like this:

[image]

if there are better solutions, or workaround please post your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug on swagger-ui 2.6.1 which sends vendorExtensions scope everytime. And that causes the requests get out of scope which results in rejected requests. Since swagger can't get the access token it can't pass oauth2

Upgrading on maven should solve the problem. Minimum version should be 2.7.0