# How to use ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant with swagger ui

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I am using swagger, swagger ui with spring rest api to get a platform for testing/documenting the API, so I need to get oAuth2 authorisation working in swagger ui, I am using password grant with the authorisation server, so I had to use `ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant` from the package `springfox.documentation.service`which has a single parameter to its constructor, namely, the token url, I am setting that to the token endpoint in my authorisation server, but unfortunately, it does not persist token url and shows that as null in the authorisation window as follows:

[image: null Authorisation URL in swagger ui]

I could not find any example to use this particular type of grant with swagger ui, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46715492/3771299)

Answer (score 0):

This is my configuration

```
public Docket oauth() {

    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).groupName("oauth")
            .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(userOAuthScheme())).securityContexts(Arrays.asList(securityContext()))
            .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()).paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .paths(not(ant("/admin/**")))
            .paths(not(ant("/admin.json")))
            .paths(not(ant("/error/**")))
            .paths(not(ant("/exception/**")))
            .paths(not(ant("/ping/**"))).build();
}

private OAuth userOAuthScheme() {
    List<AuthorizationScope> authorizationScopeList = new ArrayList<AuthorizationScope>();
    GrantType grantType = new ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant("http://localhost:8080/authServer/oauth/token");
    return new OAuth("oauth2", authorizationScopeList, Arrays.asList(grantType));
}

private SecurityContext securityContext() {
    return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).forPaths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
}

@Bean
public SecurityConfiguration securityInfo() {
    return new SecurityConfiguration("myClientId", "myClientSecret", "", "", "", ApiKeyVehicle.HEADER, "",
            " ");
}

private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
    final AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[0];
    return Arrays.asList(new SecurityReference("oauth2", authorizationScopes));
}
```

On the Swagger screen take care in the "Setup client authentication" section

```
Type: Basic auth/ Request Body
```

It depends on your implementation, in my case works Basic auth.

I dont use scopes but you can add it on

```
              AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes
              List<AuthorizationScope> authorizationScopeList
```